# How to use a default value in the constructor. How can I get this to print out 10 and then 25 to the console without adding more methods?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

class person 
{
    int age;
public:
    person(int a = 10) : age(a) {}
    int get_age() const;
};
int person::get_age() const 
{
    return age;
}
int main() 
{
    person p1;
    cout << p1.get_age() << endl; // should print 10
//insert code here
    cout << p1.get_age() << endl; // should print 25
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to get this to print out 10 and then print 25 to the console but I keep getting 10 printed out twice. I need to add a line of code to change the integers value but I am not sure what needs to be added.

Comment: `p1 = person(25);`

Comment: You can't do that without creating a new instance of the `person` class, as the comment above and the (now deleted) answer below show. You need to add a new method to the class to update the `age` property if you want to keep the same instance.

Comment: R053: Did the answer solve your problem? Do you need me to explain it in more detail?

Answer (score 3):

> I need to add a line of code to change the integers value

You can then create a temporary instance with age 25 and assign that to `p1` using the compiler generated [move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment). Example:

```cpp
int main() {
    person p1;
    std::cout << p1.get_age() << '\n';

    p1 = 25;        // <- a temporary person is created and move assigned to `p1`
    std::cout << p1.get_age() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
10
25
```

The assignment `p1 = 25;` works because the `person(int)` constructor is not [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit). `25` will then be converted to a `person` which is then assigned to `p1`.

If your constructor had been `explicit`

```cpp
explicit person(int a = 10) : age(a) {}
```

... you would have to be explicit in the assignment too:

```cpp
p1 = person{25};
```